# BufferGeometry always creates FlatShading normals. I need SmoothShading

Tags: three.js, indexed, buffer-geometry, shading

I use ThreeJS r68.

I always used `THREE.Geometry` for my project and it just works fine. 
Now I want to change from `THREE.Geometry` to `THREE.BufferGeometry` because I read that this is the better choice.
But I couldn't get SmoothShading to work with my `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

I load my Object into a BufferGeometry and call `bufferGeometry.computerVertexNormals`. And then my result is FlatShading.

I read in the `computeVertexNormals()` method that BufferGeometry calculates differently if I use an "index" attribute. I  tried to create an "Indexed" BufferGeometry but that just made everything worse. I don't know if I just created that right. I just added the indices like I would add them to the faces in a normal Geometry. The `BufferGeometry.fromGeometry()` method does not create an indexed BufferGeometry so I don't know where to look.

Do I need an indexed BufferGeometry for SmoothShading?

### UPDATE

[... some time later....]

I think I could create a indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry` now. It's more like Geometry. And smooth shading looks fine with an indexed BufferGeometry. So now i have SmoothShading but a invalid uv-map. But why is the uv-map different in an indexed BufferGeometry to compared to not indexed BufferGeometry?  BufferGeometry is really not easily loaded.

Answer (score 1):

OK.

Here is what i got:

1.) SmoothShading only works for indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry`. (as far as I know) And not for non indexed BufferGeometry.

2.) An indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry` only has 1 uv point per vertex, and not 1 uv point per face-vertex.
  That means if you have a square with 4 points, then you only have 4 uv points and not 6 like in `THREE.Geometry` and non indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry`. (That is confusing and will not allow complicated uv-maps)

### UPDATE

[... a few hours of sleep later ...]

I looked into `THREE.BufferGeometry.computerVertexNormals()` again.
And I have to correct myself.

indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry`:

1) only 1 uv per vertex 
2) only 1 normal per vertex 
result : 
  - only smoothShading possible. 
  - only simple uv maps. 
  - limit of 65.535 vertices.

non indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry`:

1) 1 uv per face vertex 
2) 1 normal per face vertex 
result: 
  - calculating normals in ThreeJS(r68): only FlatShading 
  - calculating normals outside of ThreeJS and import the normals: FlatShading and SmoothShading 
  - complicated uv maps possible

Comment: Hi. Could you please say if you think it's related to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580589/three-js-buffergeometry-how-to-control-edge-smoothing) ?

Answer (score -1):

You can apply `THREE.FlatShading` to your material to get a flat shaded indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry`. In that case you don't need to define any normals at all.

This saves you a lot of headaches and overhead:

```
geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
    color: 0xff0000, 
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
});

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Your mesh will render flat shaded.
This doesn't work for `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` yet. But they are working on it. Check the related issue [here on GitHUB](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7130).